# CSS - How can you apply Border Shadow Inset only to 2 sides?

Tags: css

I want to apply the inner shadow only to the bottom and right sides. Is there a way around this? The few hacks I have seen seem to be relating to regular border shadow, where it's easier to cover up a drop shadow then remove an inner shadow

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #161616;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #161616;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #161616;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two properties are horizontal and vertical offsets, use them.

```
box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px #161616 inset;
```